# Metropolis sampling with different proposals

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-mixture-distribution, metropolis-hastings

I implemented a metroplis sampler for a 1D gaussian mixture, the target distribution looks like this:

[image: Target distribution]

I use a 1D normal distribution as propsal, that is each candidate is sampled from a normal distribution centered around the last accepted sample with a certain standard deviation.

If I use a small variance for the proposal distribution my samples are distributed according to the target distribution although it takes a significant number of samples to achieve a good coverage.
If I increase the variance of the propsal distribution my acceptance ratio rapidly drops which was expected, but also my 10^6 samples are not distributed according to the target distribution. Especially the difference between the number of samples generated for each mode of the distribution vanishes:
[image: Samples]
I could see why this happens in the case for a proposal distribution with small variance but I don't really understand the behaviour of the sampler in the case for $\sigma = 10$ or $100$.

Could anyone explain this behaviour to me?

```
for i=1:n
while 1>0
    candidate = normrnd(x_curr,sd_prop);
    p_candidate =  eval_mixture_pdf(candidate);
    if p_candidate > p_curr || rand() < (p_candidate / p_curr) 
        samples(i) = candidate;
        x_curr = candidate;
        p_curr = p_candidate;
        break;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: In both cases, the convergence is slower, which means that 10⁶ iterations is presumably not sufficient to reach it.

Comment: I tried 10^8 iterations with $\sigma = 10$ and it doesn't chance anything (I can not attach a third image, sorry). Of course this does not proof that it's not due to the convergence but it definitely feels more like systematic bias ...

Comment: There is no mistake in your code if this is the MC core and there is no reason for "systematic bias" when running it...

Comment: @Maximal Have you tried overlaying the true density on the plots. In my experience, sometimes aspect ratios and perspectives play with our eyes.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to replicate your results and here is what happened. I think I guessed the mixture distribution almost correctly:
$$.3* N(0, 2) + .7*N(10, 2)\,. $$

I implemented the scenarios that you demonstrate. Here are my various settings:

- Monte Carlo samples of $N = 10^4$ and $N = 10^6$
- Four $\sigma$s: .1, 1, 10, 100
- Two starting values: 0 and 10

Here are the results from $N = 10^4$. Black line is the true density. Things are a little crazy here, but I don't see what you see.

[image]

Now here is the more stable $N = 10^6$. Again, I don't see what you see, and rather at $\sigma = .1$ things are a little weird, rest are all ok.

[image]

So I am not sure why you are seeing a weird behavior. It may be a starting value issue, but I doubt it. Your algorithm looks correct, so there might be a  problem with how you're storing the Markov chain (maybe?). Here is the R code for these plots (that is the only language I know).

```
set.seed(100)
## Evaluates the mixture density
eval_dense <- function(x)
{
  f_x <- .3*dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 2) + .7*dnorm(x, mean = 10, sd = 2)
  return(f_x)
}

# Samples and plots 
plot_MC <- function(sd, N = 1e6, start = 0)
{
  out <- numeric(length = N)
  accept <- 0
  out[1] <- start

  for(i in 2:N)
  {
    cand <- rnorm(1, mean = out[i-1], sd = sd)
    # Calculate ratio
    ratio <- eval_dense(cand)/eval_dense(out[i-1])
    if(runif(1) < ratio)
    {
      out[i] <- cand
      accept <- accept+1
    }else{
      out[i] <- out[i-1]
    }
  }

  x <- seq(-10, 20, length = 10000)
  truth <- eval_dense(x)
  plot(x, truth, type = 'l',
       main = paste("N =", N, ", Sigma = ", sd,", Accept = ", accept/N,  ", Start = ", out[1]),
       ylab = "density (red is MCMC)")
  lines(density(out), col = "red")
}

png("mix_mh_4.png", height = 1000, width = 800)
par(mfrow = c(4,2))
plot_MC(sd = .1, start = 0, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = .1, start = 10, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 1, start = 0, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 1, start = 10, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 10, start = 0, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 10, start = 10, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 100, start = 0, N = 1e4)
plot_MC(sd = 100, start = 10, N = 1e4)
dev.off()

png("mix_mh_6.png", height = 1000, width = 800)
par(mfrow = c(4,2))
plot_MC(sd = .1, start = 0)
plot_MC(sd = .1, start = 10)
plot_MC(sd = 1, start = 0)
plot_MC(sd = 1, start = 10)
plot_MC(sd = 10, start = 0)
plot_MC(sd = 10, start = 10)
plot_MC(sd = 100, start = 0)
plot_MC(sd = 100, start = 10)
dev.off()
```

Comment: hello from 4 years later! what would be a sensible approach to make the similar simulation using Gibbs Sampler? I am trying to sample from mixture of two bivariate normals where I know the mixture distribution similar to your answer above. I am having hard time to find the appropriate conditionals. Thanks!!